# Problem reading control effort frequency response plot

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

I am trying to plot the frequency response control effort of a control scheme in Matlab, and in particular I want to do this for different values of tau, which is a constant used to add a pole at high frequency.

The plot that i get is:

[image]

in particular, this is the control sensitivity function of a 2 dof control scheme:

[image]

and the code for obtaining the plot above is:

```
s = tf('s');
P = 1/[(1+s)*(1+0.05*s)^2];
C = (s+1)/s;

%2 DOF

tau_1 = 0.1;
CF_1 = [(1+s)*(1+0.05*s)^2]/((1+tau_1*s)^3);

tau_2 = 0.01;
CF_2 = [(1+s)*(1+0.05*s)^2]/((1+tau_2*s)^3);

tau_3 = 0.001;
CF_3 = [(1+s)*(1+0.05*s)^2]/((1+tau_3*s)^3);

Q1 = (C+CF_1)/(1+P*C);
Q2 = (C+CF_2)/(1+P*C);
Q3 = (C+CF_3)/(1+P*C);

figure;
bodemag(Q1,'r',Q2,'b',Q3,'g'),grid
legend('tau = 0.1','tau = 0.01','tau = 0.001')
```

my doubt is given by the fact that the control sensitivity function starts at zero for all the three cases. Shouldn't it start at an high value and then decrease?

In this case it does the opposite, so it starts at zero and grows until a value and stays constant there.

How do I read this plot? Or it is complitely wrong?

If I plot the step response I obtain:

[image]

from it I zoomed to show better all the coloured lines.

Can somebody help me clarify my doubts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you expect it to behave differently? Also, I believe normally the term control sensitivity is defined as $$\frac{C(s)}{1+P(s)\,C(s)},$$ so without the feedforward transfer function. Namely, this describes the transfer function from output noise to $m(t)$, while the transfer function that you are using describes the transfer function from $r(t)$ to $m(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have worked on this problem and I found that what I said was just true for the time domain. In the frequency domain we want the signal small both at low frequencies and high frequencies. But you say that I should consider ony C(s) for the control effort, but the controlled variable is m(t), so should't I consider (C(s)+C_f(s))? Thanks.

Comment: I merely wanted to clarify with my previous comment that the name "control sensitivity" usually means something different from how you used it. However, the transfer function that you are using, which includes the feedforward term, would be the correct transfer function to assess the control effort for a given reference signal.